# Releasing NSArray of non toll-free bridged objects

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, keychain

I'm trying to manage a list of keychains in my application. I get the list of keychains like this:

```
// _keychains is an instance variable in AppDelegate
_keychains = [NSArray array];
SecKeychainCopySearchList((CFArrayRef *)&_keychains);
```

So basically I get the `CFArrayRef` and convert it to `NSArray`. Now my question is how do the keychain ref objects (opaque structs) get released? Do I have to convert `NSArray` to `CFArrayRef` and use `CFRelease` (as per documentation) or is it possible to free the memory in an objective way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `[_keychains release]` when you're done with `_keychains`.  The `_keychains` object will send a `release` message to each of its elements when `_keychains` is deallocated.

Comment: But the thing is that `_keychains` array doesn't hold objects. It holds opaque structs of `SecKeychainRef`. I'm not sure if they respond to any message because documentation holds only f-tions to operate on them.

Comment: SecKeychainRefs are Core Foundation references.  They can be passed to CFRelease.  Anyway, Apple wrote the code that populates the NSArray and Apple knows that NSArray sends release to its elements.  So you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply be able to call `release` on the array. `release` will release the array and release the contents, just like in Cocoa.

In this case, there is no question how to release a CF/NS-Array, and you do not need to worry about the elements' lifetimes until the container has been released.

Even if were illegal to send `SecKeychainRef` through `CFRelease`, you should still expect this to work out because the system should do the right thing. CoreFoundation collection and allocator APIs offer enough control over allocator and store callbacks that the Security framework should do the right thing *even in the event* that the array's contents were not compatible with the default behavior (`CFRelease` in this case). They could provide their own callbacks and allocators. Since I see no documentation which states an obvious deviation from the default behaviour, I assume it is safe to call `release` on the array, and that the elements are either compatible with CF reference counting procedures, or that the collection uses a custom allocator and/or callback scheme (provided by Security) and will cleanup the elements as needed (my guess is the former).